# Genexus 16 U10 Java Web - Truncation of the response body when requesting token from external API

Tags: java, http, web, genexus

We are having problems to consume an external API with our Genexus application, through an HTTPClient variable, because when requesting the token through the Bearer method, the body in JSON format of the Response of the API arrives truncated, not being able to parse it to obtain the token received.

Sample code:

```
&httpclient = new()
&httpclient.Timeout = 30

&httpclient.AddHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8')
&httpclient.AddHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache')
&httpclient.AddHeader('Accept-Encoding','gzip, deflate, br')

&httpclient.AddVariable('client_id','aivoclient_test')
&httpclient.AddVariable('client_secret','bd8ea668-9bbc-2bda-d71e-8299f0cb98df')
&httpclient.AddVariable('grant_type','client_credentials')

&url = 'http://localhost:8085/connect/token'

&httpclient.Execute(HttpMethod.Post, &url)

if not &httpclient.ErrCode.IsEmpty()
    &validardatos = 'GENEXUS ERROR'
            + '! errorCode=' + &httpclient.ErrCode.Round(0).ToString().Trim()
            + ', errorDescr=' + &httpclient.ErrDescription
            + ', reasonLine=' + &httpclient.ReasonLine
    do 'AddMsg'
    do 'Show Messages'
    return
endif

&auxResponse = &httpclient.ToString().Trim()

msg('response=' + &auxResponse, nowait)
```

If we try to [invoke the API from POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueiJZ.png), the Response arrives without truncation, but in our GX application the TOKEN always arrives truncated, as can be seen in the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsXQZ.png) .

Analyzing the requests, the only difference is in the headers added by GX and POSTMAN, for which we believe that there must be the problem, but we have not been able to find the cause.

Does anyone have any idea where this error may be happening?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem was that the **HTTPClient** object does not work correctly always making a **POST** with the **x-www-form-urlencoded** header.
Using native Java code the response is no longer truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the variable in http://localhost:8085/connect/token is very small to return all token information.

Comment: I don't think the URL variable is the problem, as the response is truncated before reaching the GX application.
We verify this because we are monitoring the requests using a proxy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).